# Barryvdh/DomPDF - Opensans Condensed

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

After 3 hours of googling and searching, I have officially given up.

How can you load this font in Laravel/DomPDF properly?

In my controller I have:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper')->loadView('pdf', [
    'some' => $data,
]);

return $pdf->stream('my.pdf');
```

In my blade file I have:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
        html, body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
        }
</style>
```

When i output it as HTML to the screen, all is well.
As soon as i stream the pdf...nope.

I have tried @font-face as well btw.

Ps: in storage/fronts folder i do see files like
open_sans_condensed_300_9407885c3667167b0442d6efa44ed18a.ttf
open_sans_condensed_300_9407885c3667167b0442d6efa44ed18a.ufm

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741404/4875368
Sad that 4 years later, the problem is still the same